# Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src) : duplicate label in R Markdown Output PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown

[image]

I use the code below, try to output a PDF using [rmarkdown](/questions/tagged/rmarkdown), but it keeps giving me an error:

> Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sg80.png), params.src) : duplicate label 'chart'**.

I only have one chunk and name it as "chart". How can I solve this problem? Any ideas?

```
library("rmarkdown")
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 

ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = pct, label = scales::percent(pct))) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
            vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
            size = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)

render("Test2.Rmd","pdf_document")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `render("Test2.Rmd","pdf_document")` part looks suspicious. It looks like you are trying to render the document each time your render the document so it's like you are creating a loop. If you take that line out and knit your document, do you get what you want? What were you trying to do with that line?

Comment: I just begin to do RMD, so I am not pretty sure about the code, but i checked online, someone use this `render("Test2.Rmd","pdf_document")` code and works, so i tried the same way. If I delete that line and knit my document directly, then i will have an error:Error running filter..... /pagebreak.lua: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted